# What is the garden wire used for?

Tags: tools

I noticed that the wire named [Twist tie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twist_tie) is also named Garden wire. But I can't find such wires used in gardening when searching "Garden wire" on Google images.

What is the typical use for this kind of wire in gardening? For joining plants? Or for making small fences?

Comment: IMHO I use natural twines to do the job of twists because inevitably pieces of the wire break off and get in the soil and become bits of metal that will puncture your skin.  Or, they show up in the compost and you have to pick them out.  Thicker coated wires are fine for supporting vines and fences but little stingers that are sources of tetanus are BAD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite what Wikipedia says, it's not always 100% reliable as a source of information. Garden wire is NOT garden twist wire; the term garden wire may refer to large rolls of chicken wire or clematis mesh. Other types come in a roll or circular shape, may be green plastic coated or just plain wire,  and this is used for various purposes, depending on its thickness. Those purposes include stringing horizontally between hooks in a wall or fence, tightly, to provide something to tie climbing plants to as a support; I've used a heavier duty one to fix hanging bird feeders to railings, or hanging lights. It is not usually used to tie plants to anything because it's likely to damage plant stems.

Garden twist wire, on the other hand, is much, much thinner wire, rather like fuse wire, and is sheathed in broader, softer plastic which is much less likely to damage plant stems, and can be twisted to provide a light support, such as supporting a plant stem to a bamboo cane or stick. Even so, it should never be twisted in such a way that the plant stem is compressed by it; it should be wound twice round the cane and only once round the stem, and the tight twisting should be on the supporting cane or stick rather than the plant stem.

Comment: I sometimes use large fuzzy pipe cleaners. However, you have to be careful, as wire is liable to cut through even loosely bound plant stems if you get a windy day. Strips torn from old shirts, about 2-3cm wide, seem to work well for most vegetable garden plants. Again, tie loosely.

Comment: Pair of old tights or stockings work well too - but not the most aesthetically pleasing sight

Comment: Thanks, I made the confusion because some manufacturers label the twist tie as "Garden wire" - https://www.flickr.com/photos/152076002@N07/36259476094/in/album-72157686286648474/ - https://www.flickr.com/photos/152076002@N07/37094652775/in/album-72157686286648474/

Comment: Hmm, well that's very confusing isn't it! Means you always have to check what the seller means when they say 'garden wire',very annoying.